# How to convert varchar2 to a number in SQL

Tags: sql, numbers, data-conversion, varchar2

I have a column which is varchar2 and  I need to convert it to a number so I can sum up the column . When I try to convert it I get a - SQL ERROR ORA -0-1722 INVALID NUMBER. I know the issue is I need to convert the varchar2 column (extprice) to a number, but I keep getting an error when trying to do so.

Here's what I have, but I get the error

```
select to_number(m.extprice) from MA_FLF_COMB m
```

The column has dollar symbols in it for example:

```
extprice
$12.00
$7.00
```

results I want is to total the  'Extrpice' column

total = 19.00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the dollar sign in the format:

select to_number('$12.00', '$999.99')